# XY-Jax on a website

Tags: xy-pic, mathjax

I saw examples of [XY-Jax](https://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html), for instance [here](http://mathbabe.org/2012/12/17/making-math-beautiful-with-xyjax/), and I very much want to have a website in which incorporates it, enabling me to make such diagrams.

My question is very basic:
What are the steps I need to follow to obtain such a site?

Comment: Hi! Please note that while [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.